# angular.translate with $scope.$emit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am working with AngularJS and since yesterday I try to implement translations using 'angular.translate' of Pascal Precht. This works in general as following:

**app.js**

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'config', 'pascalprecht.translate'])

.config(function ($translateProvider)

{
     $translateProvider.translations("de", 
     {
         "ERROR": "Keine Wiederholung möglich!",
     });

     $translateProvider.translations("en", 
     {
         "ERROR": "No recurrence possible!",
     });
     $translateProvider.preferredLanguage("en");
})
```

**Round.controller.js**

```
$scope.save = function ()
{
    if ($scope.round.adjusted) 
    {
        if ($scope.round.variant.key === "HO")
        {
            $scope.$emit('toast', 'No recurrence possible!');
            return;
        }
}
```

My question is: What do I need to do in order to substitute the Code behind `$scope.$emit` to some with 'angular.translate' using a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject $translate to your controller and use the $translate.instant function.

```js
var errorText = $translate.instant('ERROR');
$scope.$emit('toast', errorText);
```

Comment: I would just like to add that another way to do it is inject $filter and use something like: var translate = $filter('translate');

Then you can just use translate('ERROR') in the js code.

Comment: Great; that was it! :-)